How to retrieve immediate previous row from start date and also start to end date data in Oracle SQL?
I want to retrieve data between a start date and an end date, including one immediate previous row from the start date for each row of data present in Oracle SQL. Ignore Unique id, as it is used for other purposes.
My stored procedure is working correctly for a single inRollNumber, providing both the previous and start-to-end date data. However, when I leave the roll number empty and want to retrieve all data from the database, it only fetches data between the start and end dates, not the previous record of each rollnumber.
Stored procedure code:
PROCEDURE spGetReportData
    (inEC varchar2 Default null,
     inRollNumber varchar2  Default null,
     inUserID varchar2  Default null,
     inStartDate varchar2  Default null,
     inEndDate varchar2 Default null,
     inStatus varchar2,
     inInternalStatus varchar2 Default null,
     outcursor out CURSOR_REF)
AS
BEGIN

open outcursor for
select  Result.*,Ut.FIRSTNAME ||' '||Ut.LASTNAME UserName,
CASE
                WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Result.rollnumber,Result.ec ORDER BY Result.ActivityDate ASC) > 2
                THEN Result.rollnumber || '-' || Result.ec || '-' || (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Result.rollnumber,Result.ec ORDER BY Result.ActivityDate ASC) - 2) 
                ELSE Result.rollnumber || '-' || Result.ec 
            END UniqueId
from
  (
  select DAT1.*,
  dat1.log_datetime ActivityDate
  from TBLIRGLOG_TRANSACTION_DATA dat1
  where
        dat1.status=inStatus 
        AND DAT1.INTERNALSTATUS IN ('AC','CLIP', 'CLA4')

  and   (dat1.USERID =nvl(inUserID,dat1.USERID) or dat1.USERID IS NULL)
  and   (dat1.rollnumber =nvl(inRollNumber,dat1.rollnumber) or dat1.rollnumber IS NULL)
  and   (dat1.LOG_DATETIME >= nvl(inStartDate,dat1.LOG_DATETIME) OR dat1.LOG_DATETIME IS NULL)
  and   (dat1.LOG_DATETIME <= nvl(inEndDate,dat1.LOG_DATETIME) OR dat1.LOG_DATETIME IS NULL)

UNION

select dat2.*,dat2.log_datetime ActivityDate
from
TBLIRGLOG_TRANSACTION_DATA dat2
inner join
(SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        rollnumber,
        ec,
        status,
        internalStatus,
        log_datetime,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY log_datetime DESC) AS rn
    FROM TBLIRGLOG_TRANSACTION_DATA
    WHERE
        log_datetime < inStartDate 
     AND (rollnumber = NVL(inRollNumber, rollnumber) OR NVL(inRollNumber, rollnumber) IS NULL)
)
WHERE rn = 1) dat3
on
dat2.rollnumber = dat3.rollnumber 
and dat2.ec = dat3.ec and
dat2.status = dat3.status and
dat2.log_datetime = dat3.log_datetime


where
dat2.status= instatus 
AND (DAT2.INTERNALSTATUS IN ('Admit','Enroll'))

)Result


left outer  join TBLGUIUSER UT on
Result.USERID = UT.USER_ID

where (Result.rollnumber=nvl(inRollNumber,Result.rollnumber) --OR Result.rollnumber is null
)
and( Result.ec=nvl(inEC,Result.ec) OR Result.ec IS NULL)
and (Result.USERID =nvl(inUserID,Result.USERID) OR Result.USERID IS NULL)
--and (Result.ActivityDate >= nvl(inStartDate,Result.ActivityDate) OR Result.ActivityDate IS NULL)
and (Result.ActivityDate <= nvl(inEndDate,Result.ActivityDate) OR Result.ActivityDate IS NULL)

ORDER BY
    UniqueId,Result.ActivityDate ASC;

end spGetReportData;


A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. (Make it easy to assist you. A wall of SQL code makes many turn away.)


I want to retrieve data between a start date and an end date, including one immediate previous row from the start date for each row of data present in Oracle SQL.

If you have a minimal example with the data:
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, counter, dt ) AS
  SELECT 1, LEVEL, DATE '2024-03-01' + LEVEL - 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5
UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, LEVEL, DATE '2024-03-02' + 2*(LEVEL - 1) FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3
UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 1, DATE '1970-01-01' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 2, DATE '2024-03-03' FROM DUAL;

and you want to find the rows for each id that are between the start- and end-dates of 2024-03-03 00:00:00 and 2024-03-04 23:59:59 and a single latest preceding row for each id then you can use the LEAD analytic to get the date of the next row and find rows that either match the current- or the next-date within that range:
SELECT id,
       counter,
       dt
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         counter,
         dt,
         LEAD(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt) AS next_dt
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  ( dt >= DATE '2024-03-03' AND dt < DATE '2024-03-05' )
OR     ( next_dt >= DATE '2024-03-03' AND next_dt < DATE '2024-03-05' )

Which outputs:



ID
COUNTER
DT




1
2
2024-03-02 00:00:00


1
3
2024-03-03 00:00:00


1
4
2024-03-04 00:00:00


2
1
2024-03-02 00:00:00


2
2
2024-03-04 00:00:00


3
1
1970-01-01 00:00:00


3
2
2024-03-03 00:00:00



fiddle
